# onChange in React component is not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I was writting a component for a simple React app and here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Book from "./Book";
import * as BooksAPI from "./BooksAPI";

class SearchBooks extends Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    searchedBooks: []
  };

  updateQuery = query => {
    this.setState({ query: query });
    console.log(this.state.query);
    if (this.state.query) {
      BooksAPI.search(this.state.query).then(books => {
        this.setState({ searchedbooks: books });
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-books">
        <div className="search-books-bar">
          <Link className="close-search" to="/">
            Close
          </Link>
          <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search by title or author"
              value={this.state.query}
              onChange={event => {
                this.updateQuery(event.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="search-books-results">
          <ol className="books-grid">
            {this.state.searchedBooks.map(book => (
              <div key={book.id}>
                <Book
                  book={book}
                  updateShelf={this.props.updateShelf}
                  updateBooks={this.props.updateBooks}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBooks;
```

it is supposed to be a search bar that lists books returned from the API when user types a query
I have two problems with it. First is the fact that when the call to API is send the query does not contain the last letter that was typed by the user.
And second one even when the API call is made and returned the this.state.searchedBooks array is still empty.
This is my first time working with React so I will be thankfull for any sort of help

Comment: _Beware: React setState is asynchronous_ https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3

Comment: Did you check that the backend is returning something?

Comment: It returns an array with content

Answer (score 1):

React's `setState()` is an asynchronous function.
It is asynchronous because React may batch together a multiple `setState()` calls.

Due to its nature, when you try to use `this.state.query` after `setState()`, the state has not been updated yet. To achieve your goal, you can use the second argument of `setState()`, which acts as a callback function after the state is updated.

```
this.setState({ query: query }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.query);
  if (this.state.query) {
    BooksAPI.search(this.state.query).then(books => {
      this.setState({ searchedbooks: books });
    });
  }
});
```

Reference: [React setState documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)